# shuffle array empty in class php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shuffle

cannot shuffle array declared in class.

it gives me: cannot access empty  property. I want to display a chess board. using a 2D array. the code works fine if not used as functions in a class. I want to shuffle the array and display it.

```
private $board = array(array('k', 'k', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'k', 'r'),               
             array('p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'),
             array('&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;',
             '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;'),
             array('p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'),
             array('r', 'k', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'k', 'r'));



 public function produce()
{

            shuffle($this->$board);     
            echo "<div id='inside'>";

            for($yIndex = 0; $yIndex < count($board); $yIndex++)
            {

                echo "<div class='row'>";

            for($xIndex = 0; $xIndex < count($board[$yIndex]); $xIndex++)
            {
                echo "<div class='column' data-square=$yIndex-$xIndex>
            <div class=".$board[$yIndex][$xIndex]."></div></div>";
            }
            echo "</div>";

            }

}}$a = new Display();$a->produce();
```

Comment: First hit on google gave me this,which looks like exactly your problem: http://php.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Cannot_access_empty_property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong, it should be `$this->board` instead of `$this->$board`. The second form is accessing a [variable property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), as in

```
$propertyName = 'board';
shuffle($this->$propertyName);
```